# How to read ASCII values from AT24C32 IC using Arduino? And what is serial.begin(?) in that EEPROM?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, eeprom

```
#include<Wire.h>
#include<Eeprom24C32_64.h>
#define EEPROM_ADDRESS 0x000

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  eeprom.initialize();
  const word address = 0x000;
  const byte count = 94;
  byte inputBytes[count] = { 0 };
  byte outputBytes[count] = { 0 };
  Serial.println("Read bytes from EEPROM memory...");
  eeprom.readBytes(address, count, outputBytes);
  Serial.println("Read bytes:");
  for (byte i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Serial.write(outputBytes[i]);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println("");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Next code... I have tried many sketches.

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

void setup () {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();
  for (int addr = 0x0000; addr < 0x0010; addr++) {
    Serial.print ("Address = ");
    Serial.print (addr, HEX);
    Serial.print (", value = ");
    Serial.println (EEPROM.read(addr), HEX);
  }
}  // end of setup

void loop () {
}
```

And most of the sketches check the internal EEPROM of the Arduino, not the external, stored on address 0x000. I want to read data from external AT24C32.

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried...?

Comment: @IHaveQuestion Please don't post code in the comments. Edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: @Majenko done code added plz help to solve this

Comment: @sempaiscuba done all codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know what the I2C address of your EEPROM is. Right now you have

```
#define EEPROM_ADDRESS 0x000
```

The [example from the library you cite](https://github.com/jlesech/Eeprom24C32_64/blob/master/examples/WriteReadBytes/WriteReadBytes.ino) has this:

```
/**************************************************************************//**
 * \def EEPROM_ADDRESS
 * \brief Address of EEPROM memory on TWI bus.
 ******************************************************************************/
#define EEPROM_ADDRESS 0x50
```

Then, you have to create an instance of the `Eeprom24C32_64` object:

```
static Eeprom24C32_64 eeprom(EEPROM_ADDRESS);
```

That sets up the object for the EEPROM on the right I2C address, so you can later use the `eeprom` object to read and write.

Comment: Your picture shows an LCD display. Are you expecting output to that?